# I have a flex box which contains two items to fit on one line in a confined space. How do I make right hand item overwrite the other?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex box div to fit in a limited space, it consists of two items, a category and someone's name. If the persons name is long, I want it to take preference and over the right hand end of the category (which can be hidden with `overflow: hidden`).

So for example I have this:

```
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="category">Supervisory Manager</div>
  <div class="name">Mrs Jacqueline Bennington-Smyth</div>
</div>
```

And I want the result to look like this all on one line

```
|Supervisory M Mrs Jacqueline Bennington-Smyth|
```

Even better would be this if possible

```
|Supervisor... Mrs Jacqueline Bennington-Smyth|
```

But for something less demanding of space

```
|Firefighter Decorated              John Smith|
```

Obviously totally contrived examples - but in the particular application I am working with even only 3 letters of the category will be enough, especially as a mouseover will bring up a small card with all the necessary details laid out in a better fashion.

I've been playing with `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`, but I can't quite figure out how to achieve what I want

Comment: Heads up, your are missing a closing quote in your `class="my-item` attribute at the top-level container in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go this way:

```css
.my-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
}
.my-item > div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.category {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.name {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="category">Supervisory Manager</div>
  <div class="name">Mrs Jacqueline Bennington-Smyth</div>
</div>
```

And play on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/nvLgej9d/1/).

Comment: Looks good - I just added a min-width in category to ensure I get one or two characters regardless and its perfect. Thanks